# Use Entity Framework as SSRS DataSource (.rdl files)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reporting-services

I have 100's of `.rdl` files residing in my report server & all the reports are using shared datasource and embeded datasets in each report. I was using stored procedures for querying db. All works fine here. I have some problems working with .rdl files.

1. Not able to upload the `.rdl` files one by one & specify the datasource to each uploaded `.rdl` files.
2. Also, Planning to use the web application `EDMX` as the datasource for all my reports. So that, I can use any database server to connect to my data with entity framework without changing much code changes. Because, stored procedures wont be feasible in my case.

   I need to know what is the best way of handling the above 2 scenario's. If you have some good knowledge about this, Guide me to keep going. I ll be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can programatically change the datasources of reports on the SSRS server by using the the [SetItemDataSources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.setitemdatasources.aspx) web service method.
2. You can use the [XML Connection Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220468.aspx) to have report data come in from a XML web service such as OData instead of directly from a SQL server. There are limitations with this approach (E.x.: It doesn't support the 'Refresh Fields' in the 'DataSet Properties' window). A better alternative is to create your own [Data Processing Extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152816.aspx) where you create the IDbCommand/IDataReader to connect to your EDMX and retrieve the data. This it allows you to decouple SSRS from your backend (E.x.: If you want to transfer your data as JSON, you can do that within your custom data procession extension since this isn't supported by the **XML Connection Type**.